# Openvswitch 802.3ad not working properly.

Tags: lacp, openvswitch

I have set up the catalyst and tested with standard bonding to work normally.  bond+bridge had no issues.  I then recreated using openvswitch and set bond0 to balance-tcp  the 2ndary port is now always down unless the primary is unplugged.  I verified STP is not running on the etherchannel.

Any thoughts why it would be down?

> ---- bond0 ----

```
    status: active negotiated
    sys_id: 00:25:90:87:97:9c
    sys_priority: 65534
    aggregation key: 2
    lacp_time: fast
```

slave: enp4s0: current attached
        port_id: 3
        port_priority: 65535
        may_enable: true

```
    actor sys_id: 00:25:90:87:97:9c
    actor sys_priority: 65534
    actor port_id: 3
    actor port_priority: 65535
    actor key: 2
    actor state: activity timeout aggregation synchronized collecting distributing

    partner sys_id: 00:08:7c:27:3c:00
    partner sys_priority: 32768
    partner port_id: 2057
    partner port_priority: 32768
    partner key: 1
    partner state: activity timeout aggregation synchronized collecting distributing
```

slave: enp5s0: current detached
        port_id: 2
        port_priority: 65535
        may_enable: false

```
    actor sys_id: 00:25:90:87:97:9c
    actor sys_priority: 65534
    actor port_id: 2
    actor port_priority: 65535
    actor key: 2
    actor state: activity timeout aggregation

    partner sys_id: 00:08:7c:27:3c:00
    partner sys_priority: 32768
    partner port_id: 2061
    partner port_priority: 32768
    partner key: 4097
```